# equivalent of gpresult /r with powershell without ad module

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm working on a powershell script that, after doing some stuffs, should launch one of three applications based on user AD group membership. I can't load AD module, so I'm using `gpresult.exe /r`

```
$temp = gpresult.exe /r
if ($temp -match "myAdGroup") { ... }
```

Is there a powershell command to do the same thing more efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way is:

```
$CurrentUser = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() 
$WindowsPrincipal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($CurrentUser)

if($WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole("myAdGroup"))
{
  ...
}
else
{
   ...
}
```